# How to cancel UIView animation and skip to the end?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I would like to cancel a running UIView block animation and skip to the end of it.

I am aware that starting a new animation with the option UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState stops the previous animation, but instead of beginning from the current state, I would like to begin from the "final state" of the previous animation.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you need a way of caching the end position and then use that in conjunction with a call/number of calls to immediately make the required changes, whether that's colour changes or setFrame, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send a removeAllAnimations message to the view's layer it should remove the currently active animations. Further, because the system sets the view properties to their final values as part of the animation, the view should jump to it's final position without you're having to do anything else.